# How to close a dijit TooptipDialog containing a filteringselect with an onchange event?

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to popup by itself or use a TooltipDialog to display a FilteringSelect and then close when the selection is made. The code looks a lot like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
    <script src="../dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true,parseOnLoad: true" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="dropDownButtonContainer"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
<button id='showstate' type="button"    
 onclick='document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML=stateSelect.value;'>button1</button>
<div id="result2"></div>
<script>
var filteringSelect = null;
require([
    "dojo/ready", "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect"],
     function (ready, Memory, FilteringSelect) {
    var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [{ name: "Alabama",id: "AL"},
        {name: "Alaska",id: "AK"}]
    });
    filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "state",
        value: "CA",
        store: stateStore,
        searchAttr: "name",
        onChange: function (stateSelect) {
            // This does not cause the TooltipDialog to close.
            document.getElementById("idxxx33").submit();
        }
    }, "stateSelect");
});
require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/form/DropDownButton", "dojo/dom"],
 function (ready, TooltipDialog, DropDownButton, dom) {
    ready(function () {
        var myDialog = new TooltipDialog({
            id: "idxxx33"
        });
        myDialog.addChild(filteringSelect);
        var myButton = new DropDownButton({
            label: "show tooltip dialog",
            dropDown: myDialog
        });
        dom.byId("dropDownButtonContainer").appendChild(myButton.domNode);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is for Dojo 1.8.4. Even better would be the ability to popup the FilteringSelect by itself, then close the popup with the onChange event. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to hide the TooltipDialog, you could modify your onChange function in the filteringSelect to

```
document.getElementById("idxxx33").style.visibility ='hidden'
```